# Android set character encoding

Tags: android, encoding, cp1251

How can I set the encoding of EditText value?

I tried this but it does not seem to work.

```
String test = new String(myField.getText().toString().getBytes(), "Cp1251");
```

The receiver still has invalid value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string is *always* internally (in the String class) stored as unicode.

You should specify the encoding when you convert the string to bytes, and are sending the data.

That is, invoke [getBytes(String encoding)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29) on the string, and send the resulting byte array to the receiver.

Comment: I see. I want to send this string through socket connection. But the receiver currently cannot decode it using cp1251. Do you have any idea how to encode it properly?

Comment: @Vame. Yes, see my updated reply. I'm linking to the method that you should use. You should send the `byte[]`